# set error http status in response payload in mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-esb, mulesoft, mule4

my requirement is to sent the error http status and error message in the body.
In Case of error in flow i need to pass the http code in the status field.
I can configure this http listner but don't know how to set this to get into payload. Please guide on that.
I'm expecting the MEL to get the 400 Bad Request

```
{
  'status': "400 Bad Request",
  'message': error.description
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could think of 2 ways of doing this:

1.You can use RAML and for every status code you can send appropriate responses as per your use case.This I think is the best way of doing it.

2.You can have the value for status and message key of your response body inside error handling block.Configure the 'TYPE' condition of your error handling block to catch a certain HTTP error message , then inside that you can set 2 vars: one with the status value and other with message value.Then use this vars in the Error response section of HTTP listener. You'll be ending up with many such error handling blocks if you want to address multiple status codes.

Let me know if you need further clarifications.Hope it helps.